# Why catch invoked with success promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, axios

I have maybe weird things happen I send a request to an Endpoint "/Login" and it's given me the response well!

and I do my stuff, but for some reason, I see a warning that says,

> Unhandled Promise Rejection / typeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'error.response.data')

If anybody has an explanation for it?

Code snippet

```
signIn = data => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    API.post('/login', data)
      .then(response => {
        let {
          data: {
            data: {
              response: {token},
            },
          },
        } = response;
        this.setState({loading: false});
        reactotron.log('response', response);
        reactotron.log(token);
        deviceStorage.saveKey('id_token', token);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('catched!!'); // it's appear :)
        this.setState({error: error.response.data, loading: false});
        reactotron.error(error.response.data);
      });
  };
```

=
The wrong was here in this function ~_~ !

why get me an error?

> `_deviceStorage.default.saveKey is not a function`

```
import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

const deviceStorage = {
  // our AsyncStorage functions will go here :)
  saveItem= async(key, value)=>{
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } catch (error) {
      reactotron.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
};

export default deviceStorage;
```

Comment: Add `console.log(error);` to see the value of `error`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "Error: Request failed with status code 400"!!  But when I log `error.response.data` I got my case error "email/pass is wrong" If it wrongs data

Answer (score 3):

`error` is a string representation of the error message( rejection message). But you are treating it as if it's an object when you say `error.response.data`

```
  .catch(error => {
    alert('catched!!'); // it's appear :)
    this.setState({error: error, loading: false});
    reactotron.error(error.response.data);
  });
```

Comment: Well but when just appear the alert and delete other lines I can see it!

Comment: what do you see?

Comment: I mean if i just keep alert in catch{} i see "catched"

Comment: OH I know the error, it's in `deviceStorage.saveKey()` in then {}

Answer (score 1):

The catch could be invoked if an error is encountered in the then block. Check your then block for any possible errors. That might be the reason why catch is invoked even when the promise returned success.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("resp");
});

promise1.then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
  throw 'error'
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Yup that's right in then I have an error, i see it now it's given an error `_deviceStorage.default.saveKey is not a function`